# Java client for memcachedb with replication

Tags: java, memcached, replication

I have one master and one slave memcachedb servers. I need some java client to memcache db with such opportunities:

At first it establishes connection to master server. In case if master fails the slave should become master and java client should reconnect to him. After the first server repairs they must work again in replication.

So, can you please help me to choose the best java client for memcachedb with such requirements?

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I haven't found any solutions to work with several servers in replication mode. So if you want to have the same data on several nodes you should add it manually. Also in case of some server failure you should manually reconnect to another one.

Please, let me know if you found better solution.

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework should contain support for memcached through the caching module. I know EhCache is supporter. If you are in Java, EHCache might be worth a look as it does not require that extra install process as memcached. Also, if Spring doesn't have an adapter, it should be simple to provide one to it, allowing you to switch caching implementations dynamically without changing code.

Comment: Spring doesn't support Memcached out of the box. To use memcached with Spring Cache you can try my project [Simple Spring Memcached](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/).

Comment: @ragnor according to this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/simple-spring-memecached/g6hY8cKRKaA/D-gF3kHn2t0J Simple Spring Memcached doesn't support needed features.

Comment: Simple Spring Memcached is only an abstraction over memcached client that also allows integration with Spring Cache. The master/slave replication is feature that may be supported by memcached client, so you should look at xmemcached and spymemcached clients. There is also another solution. You may try to hide both membasedb servers behind another server/service like nginx which  in case of failure of one of the servers choose another as a master. Your application should connect only to nginx serwer. It's only an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have used xmemcached as a java client with several Memcached Servers working in paralell. (Not Master/Slave(
Just one question, when you say Memcached DB which is the purpose of using Memcached? A cache or a database?

Comment: I am going to use both cache and database. My application have some part of hot keys which must be stored in the cache. If some cache entry haven't been used for a long time it must be saved into database.